# How to remove characters within parentheses of filename in R?

Tags: r

I have bunch of files and need to remove characters within parentheses of the filename. I use the following code:

```
x <- list.files()

file.rename(str_detect(x,"\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)"), "")
```

Then it turns out with the following error: invalid 'from' argument.

The input (sample of filenames):

```
abc(2020)_test1.xlsx, abc(2020)_test2.xlsx, abc(2020)_test3.xlsx
```

The expected output:

```
abc_test1.xlsx, abc_test2.xlsx, abc_test3.xlsx
```

Comment: Do you want to rename all those files on your computer or just want to change `x` ?

Comment: I need rename all in my computer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all those files are present in your working directory you can try :

```
new_x <- sub('\\(.*\\)', '', x)
file.rename(x, new_x)
```

For example if `x` is something like this :

```
x <- c('abc(2020)_test1.xlsx', 'abc(2020)_test2.xlsx', 'abc(2020)_test3.xlsx')
```

`new_x` would be :

```
new_x <- sub('\\(.*\\)', '', x)
new_x
[1] "abc_test1.xlsx" "abc_test2.xlsx" "abc_test3.xlsx"
```

Comment: It turns FALSE when I ran file.rename(x,new_x).

Comment: What does `x` return? Does it have all the filenames that you want to rename?

Comment: x returns fine as expected (as seen in the environment) but when I run the file.rename, nothing change on my computer and it returns FALSE

Comment: Try to use full path name instead. `x <- list.files(full.names = TRUE)` and then use `new_x <- sub('\\(.*\\)', '', basename(x))`

Comment: I tried `x <- list.files(full.names = TRUE)` then `new_x <- sub('\\(.*\\)', '', basename(x))` and lastly `file.rename(x, new_x)` but the same FALSE returns.

Comment: That's weird. This works for me and returns `TRUE` fro sample files on my system. Can you post `dput(head(x))` ?

Comment: `dput(head(x))` c("./101383(????)_190902.xlsx", "./101383(????)_190916.xlsx", 
"./101383(????)_190923.xlsx"). The characters within the parentheses are in korean. So, Im not sure if it is the root cause of failure.

Comment: and what is `new_x` ? Does it remove those characters?

Comment: Yep it is. `print(new_x)` 
[1] "101383_190902.xlsx" "101383_190916.xlsx" "101383_190923.xlsx"

Comment: Try `file.rename(x, paste(getwd(), new_x, sep = '/'))`

Comment: Unfortunately, `FALSE` is return instead.

Comment: Here is one sample filename that I used: 101383(수산기타)_190902.xlsx. Could you please help to check this?